# Should it be Past Perfect or Present Perfect?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect, context

Past Perfect can't be used on its own, can it?
I mean, if there is a sentence without context, just a sentence on its own, and there is no clause with predicate in Past Simple in it. Is it grammatically correct to use it in American English?

Like in this example :

> John had already given his present.

Comment: Without context nothing can be said. You have to situate your example into a context. Provide a context, that is, add  to your question the text where this sentence is found or add a text of your own in which you would want to read that example.

Comment: Please either add context with sentences before and after or make the case for the single sentence.

Comment: Absent context, why does "John had already given his present." make more or less sense than "John has already given his present"?

Comment: It's not a matter of grammar (the sentence is fine in every respect given appropriate context, it's a matter of meaningful communication. 'John had already given his present.' works given the right context and so must be grammatical, but without licensing context, sounds ridiculously incomplete and is thus unacceptable on other grounds. Just like 'It's the Flintstones.'

Answer (score 1):

The fact that people are saying that context is needed in order to know whether a sentence written using a verb in the past perfect tense "by itself" is correct or not suggests, in and of itself, that there are cases in which such utterances are indeed considered grammatically correct.  In other words, if using the past perfect tense in a sentence without any other verbs in another tense were never grammatical, then people wouldn't say that more context was needed to in order to make that determination; they would simple say that it was never correct. However, that is not the case. It *can* be used correctly in this way.

Here are some examples, with some context given after the sentence with the past perfect tense by itself:

John Knowles, *A Separate Peace*:

> **He had never been jealous of me for a second.** Now I knew that there never was and never could have been any rivalry between us. I
> was not of the same quality as he.

Margaret Mitchell, *Gone with the Wind*:

> **What a fool she had been to think she could go to Atlanta and have him for the asking, she with her scrawny neck and hungry cat eyes and
> raggedy dress!**  If she hadn't been able to pry a proposal from him
> at the height of her beauty, when she had her prettiest clothes, how
> could she expect to get one now when she was ugly and dressed tackily?
> If Miss Pitty's story was true, he must have more money than anyone in
> Atlanta and probably had his pick of all the pretty ladies, good and
> bad.  Well, she thought grimly, I've got something that most pretty
> ladies haven't got--and that's a mind that's made up.

*New York Times* headline from July 16, 1886:

> **HE HAD NEVER HEARD OF PRONOUNS**

These cases all involve a story being told in the past tense, where something happened or was done **prior to** the point in time during which the main part of the story takes place.  For example, in the *NYT* headline, we can imagine that the article was written primarily in the past tense. The article could be about someone who, at the point in time being described, once stated, "I have never heard of pronouns" (or otherwise indicated this same sentiment). Since the story of the man saying this takes place in the past (simple past tense), the present perfect construction "I **have** never **heard** of pronouns" gets expressed using the past perfect tense (and the third person) as "He **had** never **heard** of pronouns."

Comment: Hello, zunojeef. The accepted stance (on ELU and held by arguably all grammarians) is that grammaticality depends on structural acceptability, while overall acceptability is a broader concept. Thus 'John had already given his present.' is a well-formed (grammatical) sentence, as is the famous example due to Chomsky ('Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.'). However, lacking context, it does not work as totally meaningful communication and can be labelled 'unacceptable' on other grounds (violation of the Gricean maxim of quantity). (The Chomsky example is arguably just 'unacceptable' period.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The question asked specifically whether it was "grammatically correct" to use the past perfect tense on its own (without context). Grammar is typically understood to entail syntax as well as morphology, and a sentence such as "John had already given his present" is fine on syntactomorphological grounds. Even if we are to bring pragmatics (i.e., context) into consideration, the use of the past perfect tense in isolation is not inherently problematic. Consider the headline written above, intended to be understood as a standalone sentence.

Comment: 'It _can_ be used correctly in this way' either misuses 'correctly' for 'grammatically' or violates a Gricean maxim. 'John had already given his present.' is a grammatical sentence, like the nonsensical example by Chomsky; if grammaticality is the sole issue here, end of story. But ELU uses questions as a springboard, often legitimately bringing out further points.